# Lag in every action when connected through remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I am facing a 10 sec lag for everything that I do after connecting remotely from my laptop (Surface Book 2) to my desktop using Remote Desktop Connection, whether it is typing something or opening a file. Any suggestions to make it better?

Comment: Is that home, or office? So can we ask for infrastructure details, or would it be illegal?

Comment: I was connecting to my office desktop from my laptop. I just figured out that it all works as expected if the monitor doesn't go to sleep.

Comment: I can't ask you for details about your home, as it might be illegal.